# Data Scraping using urllib

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to get some data from this [link](http://www.scstrade.com/StockScreening/SS_CompanySnapShot.aspx?symbol=KEL)

To get the open price from the above link I am using the following code

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

symbols=['KEL', 'BYCO']
def keystats():
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.scstrade.com/StockScreening/SS_CompanySnapShot.aspx?symbol='+symbol)
        sourcecode = response.readlines()
        sourcecode = str(sourcecode)
        open_price = sourcecode.split('<span id="MainContent_lbl_open" style="font-weight:bold;">')[1].split('</span>')[0]
        print(open_price)

    except:
        print('Error') 

for symbol in symbols:        
    keystats()
```

I believe that above code should be able to give me result of open price as 8.20. Instead I get an Error string. Can anyone tell whats wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the string that you use to separate, if you inspect the HTML you will notice that the term is: `<span id="MainContent_lbl_open"><b>8.20</b></span>`, so you should look for those terms .

**Code:**

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

symbols=['KEL', 'BYCO']
def keystats():
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.scstrade.com/StockScreening/SS_CompanySnapShot.aspx?symbol='+symbol)
        sourcecode = response.readlines()
        sourcecode = str(sourcecode)
        open_price = sourcecode.split('<span id="MainContent_lbl_open"><b>')[1].split('</b></span>')[0]
        print(open_price)

    except:
        print('Error') 

for symbol in symbols:        
    keystats()
```

**output:**

```
8.20
21.59
```